# Ubuntu is standalone OS on my laptop. Vista install failed, Ubuntu will not run now . Help

Tags: uninstall

Ubuntu is stand alone system on my laptop, installed windows vista and got hung up after product key entry. I manually powered off laptop. now Ubuntu does not come up .. gets a

> thermal thermal_zone4 critical temperature reached
>    reboot power down

Be fore I attempted to load vista, Ubuntu and the laptop was just fine.. I shoud have uninstalled Ubuntu first, now what? your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This actually sounds like it could be a hardware failure and not an OS related issue. Hard to tell with the information you've given.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to keep Ubuntu and you have no hardware failure.
You can re-install the grub ( boot loader ) which will allow you to start up Ubuntu.

You can use your ubuntu live CD to start up the computer 
follow the following steps after you open a terminal window :

1- First step: Add the boot repair repository to your system.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

(you will be requested to enter your root  password)

2- Second step:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3- Third step:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair boot-repair
```

After all steps are completed and the application is installed.

Start the app GUI and hit Recommended repair if you only have one HDD installed.

I guess in laptop configuration , only one HDD is installed.

The above should get you started if there is not hardware failures.

Comment: Thank you .. I can get to the grub window ans crub command line.. ones I hit enter it takes and error and reboots and powers down

Comment: You could be facing a hardware failure !! Can you start the computer with a live CD ?